# How to signing on computer with private key in Android's app data

Tags: android, certificate, private-key, signing, pkcs#11

I am using [SoftHSMv2](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2)
as cryptoki library for both Android and PC. I want to using Android device to replace an USB token and signing on PC with a certificate and key pair stored in my Android app data.
Just import the certificate from Android into PC's cert store are enough to PKCS#11 perform signing?
Do I need modify PKCS#11 library to push data to Android or any other modify?

Comment: Seems _SoftHSM depends on a cryptographic library, Botan or OpenSSL_. Is this working on Android?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have soft token on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify which operating systems on PC you are targeting I'm assuming that Windows one of them.

Windows itself doesn't support PKCS#11 standard and it has its own interface called CryptoAPI. So, if you want to perfom signing operation in such programs as Microsoft Outlook you need to implement a [Cryptographic Service Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa380245(v=vs.85).aspx) (CSP)
 or [Key Storage Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931355(v=vs.85).aspx) (KSP). Or if your android device represents in system as a smart card you could implement [Smart Card Minidriver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/smartcard/smart-card-minidrivers). Schematic it will be something like this:

```
Windows -> YOUR_CSP (or YOUR_KSP) -> pkcs11 -> anroid device

Windows -> Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider 
(or Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider) -> SCMinidriver -> pkcs11 ->android device
```

[Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30688) you can get the SDK.

Also you should know that still not all programms supports KSP (only CSP).

Note that Windows 7 and below requires that CSP dll [must be signed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/authenticode-signing-of-csps) with Code Signing certificate.

Comment: Since the private key cannot export from Android device, how PKCS#11 push data into device to signing? Can I create my own PKCS#11 library for push data or fake slots?

Comment: Yes, you can. For example: CryptSignHash(data_in, data_out) ->
your_csp.CPSignHash(data_in, data_out){ pkcs11.C_SignInit(); pkcs11.C_Sign(data_in, data_out); }